# Why does CPU usage increase fourfold after upgrading PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, cpu, php

We have a portal that attracts high traffic. Since ubuntu's 18 has come to the end of its life, we have upgraded the servers running php 7.4 on ubuntu 18. The average load of servers running Ubuntu 18 and php 7.4 is 0.5, while the average cpu load of servers running Ubuntu 20 and php 8 is 2. the php-fpm status page has an average of 15-20 connections.

On the front side, the F5 distributes the tradfik in a natural way. why can there be an average 4 times cpu usage difference between the "ubuntu 18 and php7.4" machines and the "ubuntu 20 and php8" machines? Dec.18 and php7.4 machines.dec.18 and php7.4 machines.dec.18 and php7.4 machines?

All fpm and core parameters are the same way! We tried to upgrade Ubuntu 20 from 18, the same again. We tried installing Ubuntu 20 again, the same.

also, when I activate the jit that comes with php 8, we disable the jit because we observe that the 12gb memory comes to an end within a few hours. In addition, we could not observe any difference in performance at the time the jit was running.

There is no record in the system logs that the operating system has reached its limits.

```
fpm settings
pm= static
pm.max_children =50
pm.max.requests = 500

opcache:
zend_extension=opcache.so
acache.activate =1
acache.enable_cli=1
acache.memory consumption = 4096
acache.max_accelerated files=5000
acache.revalidate_freq=60
acache.validate_timestamps=1
acache.file_update_protection=0
acache.max_wasted_percentage=10
acache.interned_strings_buffer=32
acache.validate_permission=1
acache.validate_root=1

ubuntu 18/20
8 cores
12 gb of ram

ubuntu # ulimit -a
kernel file size (blocks, -c) 0
data segment size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
timing priority (-e) 0
the file size (blocks, -f) is unlimited
pending signals (-i) 96157
maximum locked memory (kbytes, -l) 65536
the maximum memory size (kbytes, -m) is unlimited
open files (-n) 131072
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message sequences (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
maximum user operations (-u) 131072
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: *If* you cannot resolve this, consider that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS *with expanded support* is through Q1 2028 . For individual use (up to 5 machines), it's free, but licensed for commercial use: https://ubuntu.com/pro

Comment: Hi George, the fact that you have few free memory can depend on how the new system free the unused one. Until you do not observe differences in performance you should not be too much worried. BTW passing from 18 to 20 can enable many different things included indexing processes. A question have you tried Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS? Good Luck.

Comment: since ubuntu 18 is the end of life, there is only ubuntu 20 and 22. we are having the same performance problem in 2 distributions.